# Bind XML Data to ASP.net ListView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, xml, listview

I have following ListView defined in ASPX page and a C# webmethod which returns an XML string. I want to bind the ListView with the XML data returned by the webmethod. Also, I want to use JQuery to do this binding. I am able to bind this XML data to GridView using JQuery however, the same does not work with ListView. Please let me know what changes needs to be done in order to accomplish this.

**ASPX page List view** -

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table class="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" rules="rows">
            <tr class="headerRow">
                <th style="width: 40px;">
                    ID
                </th>
                <th style="width: 230px;">
                    Name
                </th>
                <th style="width: 230px;">
                    Fee
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="testCss">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span id="id">
                        <%# Eval("ID") %>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="name">
                        <%# Eval("Name")%></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="fee">
                        <%# Eval("Fee")%>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

**C# Web method** -

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetCustomers(int pageIndex)
    {
        string query = "some SQL Query";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);

        return GetData(cmd).GetXml();
    }

    private static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        string strConnString = @"some connection string";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds, "Customers");
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**JQuery function to bind XML data to GridView** - 
I want to know how I can write similar function to bind this XML data to ListView mentioned above.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        GetCustomers(1);
    });

    function GetCustomers(pageIndex) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "JQuery_BindListView_snippetExample.aspx/GetCustomers",
            data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }

    function OnSuccess(response) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
        var xml = $(xmlDoc);
        var customers = xml.find("Customers");
        var row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
        $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr").not($("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:first-child")).remove();
        $.each(customers, function () {
            var customer = $(this);
            $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("Last_Name").text());
            $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("First_Name").text());
            $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("EMail_Id").text());
            $("[id*=gvCustomers]").append(row);
            row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
        });
    };
</script>
```

I am new to JQuery. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're saying that the data type expected from the web method is `json` then you're parsing xml ? Which is it ?

Comment: Ohh.. I didn't notice that.. But somehow, this is working fine with GridView. I don't know how and why!